# How to take id on squarespace gallery and call a single element on css

Tags: html, css, gallery, squarespace

I have a gallery block on my squarespace site, and I need to put animation just on a couple of these images, but I can't figure out how to take single element, or pick up id and use it in css.
I know for sure that I cannot use Yui id because they are not static.

What can I do?
I heard about a theory: 
On the link image

https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ONELINKID/SECONDLINKID/THIRDLINKID/IMAGE.PNG
ONELINKID/ Is the gallery id
SECONDLINKID/ this is the gallery id
THIRDLINKID/ wrapper
IMAGE.PNG/ image

If this is true, is possible to recall one of this id on the css to make the animation on the single element?
And in case, how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's possible to target the entire gallery block but not a specific image inside the block.

This is possible (targeting the entire gallery block) :

```
#block-9402f7f162de95970c9c {
  display:none;
}
```

But this is not (targeting one image inside the block) :

```
#yui_3_17_2_1_1451403688334_177 {
  display:none;
}
```

The id of the specific image in the block was pulled from inspecting the element, not from the URL of the image as you hinted might be possible. Each image inside the block does have a unique id associated with it, but targeting the id through CSS does not seem possible with SquareSpace.